# The 'can' confusion

Tags: modal-verbs, can-could

Every time there is a lesson on modals I am taught that the modal 'can' is about ability. 
How should I determine when 'can' literally means ability, and when it is just a request? Does the question 'Can I say a bird is ON the tree?' sound a bit provocative for a native speaker?
Is it appropriate to answer the 'Can I ...' questions with 'Yes, you can, but actually (it would be wrong/you're not allowed to...).'?

Can this modal be used in a non-modal way like 'canned' or 'canning' (describing ability in maybe a humorous context, not food processing), and if it could, what would the meaning be?

Comment: You should be able to understand it from context. It can be used to say something is possible or allowed, or that somebody has the ability to do something.

Comment: `Does the question 'Can I say a bird is ON the tree?' sound a bit provocative for a native speaker?` No, not at all. It's just a straightforward question.

Comment: Just a note: native English speakers don't say that birds are *on* trees, but rather that they're *in* trees.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your English seems fine. I suspect you're easily able to tell by the context whether the "can" of a sentence is about ability, possibility, permission, etc.

And there's nothing provocative about the question you propose.

The answer is yes to both of your other questions about "can", to the point that they would seem trite for a native speaker to ask, and almost like asking "is wordplay possible?".

It wouldn't be unusual to answer a "can I" question with "yes, you can, but" if what came after the "but" were a sincere warning of a possible negative outcome, for example, rather than "it's not permissible", since the "can" is obviously implying a request for permission or the exploration of a possibility.

However, "yes you can but no you can't", as you're implying, wouldn't usually be a straight answer, particularly without some explanation as to the reason for the ambivalence. (And if such a reason were to be provided, the preceding phrase would often be just "yes and no".)

But as a sort of joke meaning  "yes, you're physically able to (or it's within the realm of possibility), but no, you're not allowed", sure, it's possible, and variations on this theme are not unheard. So no you can't, but yes you can. If you want to risk annoying your interlocutor.

And as for "canned" and "canning", sure, but possibly with more potential to confuse your listener, depending on the context. It's hard to say precisely what they would mean, without context, but "canned" might mean "demonstrated [s/he] was able to", and "canning" might be "demonstrating [s/he] is able to". Whether it would seem funny or not, I'm not willing to guess. ;-)